# How to implement Promise.race() with async/await

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

How can I implement Promise.race() method with async and await?

```
async function promiseRace(promises) {
  const results = [];
  for (const p of promises) {
    await p;
    results.push(p);
  }
  return results[0];
}
```

I've tried to implement it like above but this doesn't work.

Comment: What specific problem you are facing?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To improve this question show us what you have done. Show source code and describe what it is doing and what you need it to do. See [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @CharlieWallace, I am not sure how that copy/paste comment applies to this question. The question shows what they have done, and there is source code. They tell us what it needs to do (Promise.race), and we can run their code and see it indeed does not work. So why did you post this comment?

Comment: @trincot, I am looking for more than "this doesn't work" in the question. The question can be improved by more explanation as to what the behavior is that does not work.

Comment: The race part does not  work. It always resolved/rejected with first parameter given to promiseRace function: promiseRace(fisrtPromise, secondPromise). Even if secondPromise resolved/rejected faster it still return firstPromise result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't. Just like you cannot implement the `Promise` constructor using `async`/`await`. Remember that `await` is only syntactic sugar for `then` calls - and you cannot implement the basic promise combinators using only that.

Comment: i basically can't understand your answer. why it can't possible ? if it synthetic sugar it mean there is more long way to do that. so it can

Comment: What I'm saying is that you cannot implement `Promise.race` with only `.then()` (without `new Promise`), and since `await` is only syntactic sugar for `.then()` (not doing more) you cannot use only that either.

Answer (score 8):

You can't. When using `await` you halt execution onto *one specific* promise. To implement `Promise.race` manually, you have to fiddle with callbacks:

```
function race(promises) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     for(const promise of promises)
        promise.then(resolve, reject);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can by using a wrapper promise along with async await. In the wrapper promise, protect the resolve/reject so that only the first promise wins.

**Promise.race example using async/await:**

```js
// Implements promise.race
const race = async (promises) => {
  // Create a promise that resolves as soon as
  // any of the promises passed in resolve or reject.
  const raceResultPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Keep track of whether we've heard back from any promise yet.
    let resolved = false;

    // Protect the resolve call so that only the first
    // promise can resolve the race.
    const resolver = (promisedVal) => {
      if (resolved) {
        return;
      }
      resolved = true;

      resolve(promisedVal);
    };

    // Protect the rejects too because they can end the race.
    const rejector = (promisedErr) => {
      if (resolved) {
        return;
      }
      resolved = true;

      reject(promisedErr);
    };

    // Place the promises in the race, each can
    // call the resolver, but the resolver only
    // allows the first to win.
    promises.forEach(async (promise) => {
      try {
        const promisedVal = await promise;
        resolver(promisedVal);
      } catch (e) {
        rejector(e);
      }
    });
  });

  return raceResultPromise;
};

// *************
// Test Methods
// *************
const fetch = async (millis) => {
  await waitMillis(millis);
  return 'Async result: ' + millis + ' millis.';
};

const waitMillis = (millis) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve();
    }, millis);
  });
};

const run = async () => {
  let result;

  result = await race([fetch(1), fetch(2), fetch(3)]);
  console.log('Winner', result);

  result = await race([fetch(3), fetch(2), fetch(1)]);
  console.log('Winner', result);

  result = await race([fetch(10), fetch(3), fetch(4)]);
  console.log('Winner', result);
};

run();
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not:

```
const race = async (promiseArr) => {
    return Promise.race(promiseArr)
}
```

And inside your async function:

```
let dayAtTheRace = await race([
    my.promiseFunc(),
    my.wait(10)
])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function promiseRace(promises) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    promises.forEach(async (promise) => {
      try {
        const result = await promise;
        resolve(result);
      } catch (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you explain how your code works and why it's a solution to the problem?

Comment: if he used ``await``, what he wanted was something similar to ``Promise.all()``

Answer (score -2):

Here is my solution:

```
   async function promiseRace(promises) {
  const results = [];
  for (const p of promises) {
    results.push(await p);
  }
  return results[0];
}
```